Ant Colony Optimization and Genetic Algorithms in Terms of Efficiency in Solving the Traveling Salesman Problem
How could I gather data for an experiment solving the traveling salesman problem by comparing ant colony optimization to genetic algorithms in terms of efficiency? Are there any recommended tools? My goal is to gather the data firsthand on my laptop. 
I tried to understand the concepts, and I am still looking for a program that could run the simulation for both algorithms, preferably in Java.

It’s not clear what you’re asking. You’d need to decide what you man by “efficient” and measure implementations of your algorithms. Are you looking for a tool that dots everything except the algorithms?

You can just generate "random" data. Then, simply compare your both algorithms.

Note that these algorithms have high time complexities. If you don't know much about these algorithms, be informed that you really need memory and CPU powers. With personal PCs, it would be very tedious. I prefer classic algorithms, over these heuristic and "evolutionary" algos.
